# Find closest factor to a number, of a number

Tags: java, algorithm, math

I am trying to automate the finding of the closest factor of a number to another number;

**Example:**

Closest factor of 700 to 30 is 28 (30 does not go into 700, but 28 does).

An obvious solution is just to get all the factors of 700 and do a simple distance calculation to find the nearest factor to 30, but this seems to be inefficient.

Another solution is to find all the base prime factors, like:

```
private List<Integer> getPrimeFactors(int upTo) {
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 2; i <= upTo; i++) {
        if (upTo % i == 0) {
            result.add(i);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

And multiplying each of these numbers together to get all the combinations, and therefore find the closest.

I am trying to programme this so it is automated. 
Any better solutions?

Comment: this is a math problem, if you have a programming problem please state it

Comment: How is this not a programming problem?

Comment: Keep decrementing your number (30) until you find one where `input % value == 0`. Don't know if it's more efficient though :-)

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen dont forgett incrementing

Comment: @kai Depends on the definition of "nearest".

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen nearest is nearest, above or below

Comment: In that case: incrementing and decrementing. Definitely doesn't sound efficient now :)

Comment: @Cobbles you are asking for a better algorithm. its not really a coding problem. so i agree to no idea for name. and you tagged it with math :D

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I agree :/ but it looks like the only one

Comment: Can we put this is into either Math or Algorithms section, as this is not a programming problem

Comment: I can't find an algorithms section? I've added the Algorithm tag though.

Comment: You can factorize the number, then search the factorization for the combination of factors that get closest to the max without going over. Branch and bound is rather helpful here, yet skip those which would exceed the max once you exceed the max. Also good to treat the factorization as a multiset, which should prevent repetitive things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have my solution wrapped in a small static method:

```
/**
* @param target the number you want the factor to be close to
* @param number the number you want the result to be a factor of
*/
private static int getClosestFactor(int target, int number) {
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        if (number % (target + i) == 0) {
            return target + i;
        } else if (number % (target - i) == 0) {
            return target - i;
        }
    }
    return number;
}
```

Comment: What means number and what means max? This seems to be completely wrong.

Comment: @Udo care to elaborate? Number is the number you want the factor to be close to, and max is the number you are dividing by.

Comment: Rename `number` to `target`, rename `max` to `number`, and don't forget to check if `number%target==0`.

Comment: Ok, that generally works, but on first return you certainly mean `return target + i`. And it hat problems with some extreme values. if `target = 0` it will crash. if `target < -2 * number` you will get `number` as result, but it should be `1` (if only positive factors a required).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to calculate all factors, but you can go in both directions from the number to find its closest number which is the factor of given number

Pseduo code will be:

```
n= given number(dividend);
x= second number( whose closest number is required)
i=0;
if(n%x==0) print x;
else
while(true){
   if(n%(x-i)==0){
      print x-i
      break 
   }
   else if(n%(x+i)==0){
     print x+i;    
       break 
   }
   else i=i+1
}
```

Comment: What happens to your (pseudo)code for `n=19` and `x=3`...?

Comment: @CiaPan: It appears to me as though the code would print `1`.

Comment: Yes, it would print 1 because it is the closest number which satisfies given conditions

Comment: Ahh, yes, you're both right. I must have misread the code... BTW, the first `if..else` is not necessary, same test will be done (twice) in first `while` iteration with `i==0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    package dummy;

    public class test {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int factorOff = 700;
            int factorFrom = 30;
            for (int i = 2; i < factorOff; i++) {
                if (factorOff % (factorFrom + i) == 0) {
                    System.out.println(factorFrom + i);
                    i = factorOff;
                } else if (factorFrom - i > 1 && factorOff % (factorFrom - i) == 0) {
                    System.out.println(factorFrom - i);
                    i = factorOff;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be a fast solution:

```
public static int findClosestFactor(int number, int closeTo) {
    int result = 1;
    int currentDist = closeTo - 1;
    // stop conditions for comparison
    boolean compareSmallFactor = true;
    boolean compareLargeFactor = true;
    for (int factor1 = (int) Math.sqrt(number); factor1 > 0; factor1--) {
        if (number % factor1 == 0) {
            if (compareSmallFactor) {
                int dist1 = Math.abs(closeTo - factor1);
                if (dist1 < currentDist) {
                    result = factor1;
                    currentDist = dist1;
                }
                // factor 1 is getting always smaller
                // so you need not compare next time, if go away from target (smaller than target)
                if (factor1 <= closeTo) {
                    compareSmallFactor = false;
                }
            }

            if (compareLargeFactor) {
                int factor2 = number / factor1;
                int dist2 = Math.abs(closeTo - factor2);
                if (dist2 < currentDist) {
                    result = factor2;
                    currentDist = dist2;
                }
                // factor 2 is getting always larger
                // so you need not compare next time, if go away from target (larger than target)
                if (factor2 >= closeTo) {
                    compareLargeFactor = false;
                }
            }

            // if both factors go away from target, you can cancel
            if (!compareSmallFactor && !compareLargeFactor) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can factorize the number, then use a powerset generator (for a multiset[1]) to search for the group of factors that get closest to the max without going over.

The powerset generator can be modified to prevent further iteration down branches that exceed the desired value (branch and bound). IE: if factors are `(2,5,7,13,19)`. The number is `80`, and you have `2*5*7 = 70. 2 * 5 * 7 * 13 = 910`. There is no need to check `2 * 5 * 7 * 19` as it would clearly exceed the max.

[1] It's a good idea to treat the factorization as an multiset. For example in the case of `700, ((2,2),(5,2),(7,1))`. You could treat it as (2,2,5,5,7), but it would do extra work since there's no need to find 2 * 5 = 10 more than once, but if it's not treated as a multiset, then that would happen.