# How to get a submap with LinkedHashMap?

Tags: java, performance, dictionary, iteration

Currently, I'm using `TreeMap` to store some x and y coordinates but the iteration is very slow compared to an `ArrayList` or `HashMap`. I'm using it because I need the `subMap()` method so I can get X values in a determined range even if the exact X value (key) doesn't exists.

`LinkedHashMap` has almost the same speed of a `HashMap` and I can iterate the keys in the insertion order (I need insertion order or order by comparator as it is done in TreeMap) but I don't have a `submap()` method. In TreeMap I can generate submaps very fast.

Is there any data structure or some way to store ordered values (by insertion order or comparator) faster than TreeMap that allows to get submaps in a range even if the exact value is not in the map? I mean, maybe I want values between 2 and 25 but 2 doesn't exist, the nearest is 3 so it will return a submap from 3 to 25. Or some way to add this functionality to `LinkedHashMap`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I finally got the answer to my problem. After a few test `HashMap`, `LinkedHashMap` and `TreeMap` are way slower than `ArrayList` and I wanted to use them just for the ability to create `subMaps()`. So I created a new class extending `ArrayList` which gives me a very good performance and with the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19198826/1335209) answer I created fast way of getting a sublist by values not by index. Here is the complete class:

```
/**
 * The purpose of this class is to be a faster replacement to a {@link java.util.TreeMap} with
 *  the ability to get sublist containing a range of x values. ArrayList access time is O(1) while
 *  {@link java.util.TreeMap} is O(log(n)). When large data is handled the impact on performance is
 *  noticeable.
 */
public class XYDataset extends ArrayList<PointValue> {

    private final float COMPARISON_THRESHOLD = 0.01f;

    final Comparator<PointValue> comparator = new Comparator<PointValue>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(PointValue lhs, PointValue rhs) {
            if (Math.abs(lhs.getX() - rhs.getX()) < COMPARISON_THRESHOLD) return 0;
            return lhs.getX() < rhs.getX() ? -1 : 1;
        }
    };

    public XYDataset(int capacity) {
        super(capacity);
    }

    public XYDataset() {
    }

    public XYDataset(Collection<? extends PointValue> collection) {
        super(collection);
    }

    @Override
    public List<PointValue> subList(int start, int end) {
        return super.subList(start, end);
    }

    /**
     * Generate a sublist containing the range of x values passed
     * @param x1 lower x value
     * @param x2 upper x value
     * @return sublist containing x values from x1 to x2
     */
    public List<PointValue> subList(float x1, float x2){
        /**
         * Collections.binarySearch() returns the index of the search key, if it is contained in the list;
         *  otherwise it returns (-(insertion point) - 1).
         * The insertion point is defined as the point at which the key would be inserted into the list:
         *  the index of the first element greater than the key, or list.size() if all elements in the list
         *  are less than the specified key. Note that this guarantees that the return value will be >= 0 if
         *  and only if the key is found.
         */
        int n1 = Collections.binarySearch(this, new PointValue(x1, 0), comparator);
        int n2 = Collections.binarySearch(this, new PointValue(x2, 0), comparator);

        /**
         * Example, we assume the list is sorted. Based on (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198586/search-sorted-listlong-for-closest-and-less-than)
         *
         * long X = 500;
         * List<Long> foo = new Arraylist<>();
         * foo.add(450L);
         * foo.add(451L);
         * foo.add(499L);
         * foo.add(501L);
         * foo.add(550L);
         *
         * If we search for something that isn't in the list you can work backward from the return value
         *  to the index you want. If you search for 500 in your example list, the algorithm would return (-3 - 1) = -4.
         * Thus, you can add 1 to get back to the insertion point (-3), and then multiply by -1 and subtract 1 to get
         *  the index BEFORE the first element GREATER than the one you searched for, which will either be an index that
         *  meets your 2 criteria OR -1 if all elements in the list are greater than the one you searched for.
         */
        if(n1 < 0) n1 = -n1-1;
        if(n2 < 0) n2 = -n2-1;

        return this.subList(n1, n2);
    }
}
```

`PointValue` is a just a class that contains x and y coordinates. So now I just call `subList()` passing the range of x coordinates I want. In my case the insertion order is also sorted which is important in order to use `Collections.binarySearch()`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need a TreeMap which has iteration which is not much slower than LinkedHashMap and does what you really want.  As HashMap is unordered, a subMap has no meaning.

Comment: I'm currently using TreeMap but it's really slow compared to a HashMap or ArrayList with O(1) access

Comment: @Andres Is it the access time or the iteration time which is the concern?

Comment: It's the iteration time, I'm iterating over 500k entries. But if access time is lower, iteration time should be lower or not?

Comment: @Andres iterating is a different operation to random access and I wouldn't expect it to be the same.